# Resize control on Main Form resize (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I created a user control which is a Grid of TextBlocks with fixed height rows and fixed width each. I place this control on a main form. Then on the run time I read current height of the control and based on this value I calculate number of rows to display. 
Now, the problem is, when I resize main form: how can I update number of rows based on the new height of the main form?

edit: saying Grid of textblocks I meant a grid layout of texblocks

Comment: why do you reinvent all of this instead of defining the grid layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a handler to the Window.SizeChanged event and re-size your Grid there

Comment: Of course, it was obvious and I tried it with no success, but the reason was that I incorrectly specified the name of the control and could not get an access to it from main form. Now as I corrected it, everything is fine. Thanks for help!